# Summing groups in pandas groupby object - AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas

I have a groupby object called `groups`.  There are 29 groups and I am trying to sum all of the rows for each group and create a new dataframe with all of the summed groups.

```
summed = [i.sum for i in groups]
```

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sum'

Comment: Would you give us a short reproducible example of your code?

Comment: It looks like you're confused about what `groups` is (it's a list of tuples after your second assignment.)  In your original example, you had the uid index/column, the dc ones you wanted to group, and then the rest of the columns.  What *exactly* do you want to sum?

Comment: @DSM i restored the previous question I will post a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**: *this question was formulated in another way when this was answered. Now it includes the solution posted here.*

You have to do `sum(i)` instead of `i.sum()` as `i` is a tuple.

Example:

```
>>> a=(1,2,3,5,6)
>>> sum(a)
17
```

Comment: getting this error now `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 7, placement implies 15`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Meepl, that's not the summing problem. Where does the error appear?

Comment: Updated my code above. It does happen after the summing list comprehension.

Comment: @Meepl, that's a __completely different question now__!

Comment: i know, apologies haha.  Should I delete and repost?

Comment: No, leave the current question, mark the answer as correct, then create a new question.

Comment: Please put the question back the way it was, then open a new question.

Comment: @TheBlackCat is there a way to restore to previous version of the question?

Comment: Yes, see here for instructions (with pictures): http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101550/288415